# Running a javascript function from code behind

Tags: c#, javascript

I know you can do this with the following

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript
```

But is there a cleaner way to do this. I heard this is a messy way of calling jscript functions and i should never do it. Is this true?

Comment: Do you have any specific scenario ?

Comment: Hi, On a button click inside an update panel. Run a block of code and then call the javascript function

Comment: i have a cleaner way but it depends on you code , i mean if you wont to run your javascript after a specific server button click it also depends on where is the button if its on update panel you can attach add_beginRequest and add_endRequest event to the update panel through the pageLoad method to handel if a specific button click on the end request do something on the other hand if your button is clean with out update panel you should use window.onload event and catch the cause post back element from there if you need a complete scenario i can give you one if that's what you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript` *is* the clean way of doing this.

I think that outputting javascript directly to the page (`Response.Write`) or onto a `Literal` control is messier.

Answer (score 0):

I am not fully aware about what the best practice is. But in my case I use jGrowl to notify the user whether an action either succeded or failed, i.e.:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page,
    typeof(Page), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
    "$.jGrowl('The Group was successfully created, { theme: 'succeeded'});", true);
```

Hope this helps!